# Basic help using includes

Tags: php, include

I'm having a basic issue, this is really a getting started problem, documentation isn't helping!
I have an index.php with the following in my html root directory, containing

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Spike</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php           
            include __DIR__ . 'testInclude/data.php';
            $dataObj = new testClass;
            $data = $dataObj->GetData();
            echo "$data" 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

In a subfolder called testInclude I have a file called data.php which contains

```
<?php
class testClass
{
    public function GetData()
    {
        return "Hello World";

    }
}
?>
```

The main page is rendering (the title displays and if I add html it works, but otherwise, I get nothing.
Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks

J

Comment: Maybe because *\_\_DIR\_\_ ... This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory*, so you need something like `__DIR__ . '/testInclude/data.php'`

Comment: Sigh, that works.  Such an obvious error, I'm embarrassed!  Post as an answer and I'll accept :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
include __DIR__ . 'testInclude/data.php';
```

To this:

```
include __DIR__ . '/testInclude/data.php';
```